Selecting point demanding on distance and date with QGIS Expression
I have a point layer with different attributes, and one is a date (dd.MM.yyyy).

For the first date, I select all points.
For the next date, I select all points, if they are further than 100
meters of the points of the first date.
For the third date, I select all points, if they are further then
100 meters of all the points of all the steps before.

My problem is that my layer has different numbers of date. So I need a generic expression (for_each or something like that).

Are those dates fixed? If not, how are they chosen? Is this a one-time-job, or a repeating task? Are those new selections, or additions to the first selection?

To solve this operation, we need an expression that compares the distance to all the points of the previous dates. Here is a possible solution:
with_variable(
    'current_date',
    "date_field",  -- your data field
    
    -- Check if there are no previous points within 100m
    array_length(
        -- Filter points that are less than 100m away
        array_filter(
            -- Get all point IDs with the previous date
            array_agg(
                $id,
                filter:= "date_field" < @current_date
            ),
            -- Calculate the distance to each point
            distance(
                $geometry,
                geometry(
                    get_feature_by_id(
                        @layer,
                        @element
                    )
                )
            ) < 100
        )
    ) = 0
)

Important Notes:

Change "date_field" to the actual name of your date field
The distance is in meters (change 100 if you need another distance)
The expression assumes the CRS is in meters

